# Add entity_id column and filter in sales order grid magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, filter, order-grid

I want to add entity_id column and filter for its search in sales_order_grid in magento 2.3 admin. Any one have any idea?

Comment: in sales_order_grid already added entity_id columns in this table. Please explain what want to ?

Comment: nope. That's order increment id. entity_id is the field used in db for processing order.